# RPC::XML::Server library in Perl

Tags: perl, xml-rpc

I would like to get some experiences of using RPC::XML::Server library in Perl, especially the stability and robustness issues. Also would like to get comparison to some other Perl libraries regarding this kind of usage

Answer (score 1):

We're building up some data accessors using RPC-XML on a system that doesn't offer client/server ability. We've just started so I can't comment on robustness, but creating the libraries and testing them has been really easy.

It took me about an hour to build sample code for a Perl server and client, then clients in Ruby and Python so I could show the interoperability. The code was for one of our network engineers, who loves it.

I like it because it's so simple he can take care of the coding, and I'm doing code reviews with him, to keep him following the Perl way.

Comment: Thank you very much! I also managed to make some sample code for both client/server in perl and it was very easy. But, consideration of using it a bit harder is what we are to take, so I need some experienced users

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a more complex scenario, but I'm not using RPC-XML, I may consider that option in the future. I'm currently using Frontier::Daemon for an XML-RPC server. I believe the scenario would still be just as complex if I used RPC-XML instead.

I'm using XML-RPC server in combination with Perl reflection to dynamically serve XML-RPC methods from an external library/module. I built it for use as a Perl test library server for Robot Framework test automation framework.

Unfortunately, I haven't gotten it to fully work. Library works executing locally but fails when used for XML-RPC, which was the intent.

You can review my project here: http://code.google.com/p/plrobotremoteserver/

FYI, I used Frontier::Daemon, because at the time I was doing this project, the online docs seem to show that Frontier was easier to work with.